# JS For loop counter don't work in nested loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to build a Google AppsScript based WebApp. I am preparing a JSON object for an API call in some nested `for` loop. I can't figure out why, but counting variables in the third nested loop can't be used. 
I am trying to push() some value into the object by using counting variables (i, j, k), but inside the if condition they don't work. The condition works, despite I can Log values of these counting variables the push() command doesn't work. No error reported.

```
var APIPayloadObject = {};
APIPayloadObject.update = [];

for(i=0; i < orders.length; i++){
   ...
   APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items = [];

   for(j=0; j < lineItems.length; j++){
      APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items.push({id: lineItems[j].id});
      ...
      for(k=0; k < lineItemMeta.length; k++){
      APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data = [];
      // APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data.push({id: k}); // This line is not necessary, but works.
      ...
      if( lineItems[j].product_id == productID && lineItemMeta[k].key == 'Utánrendelve' ){
         APIPayloadObject.update[0].line_items[0].meta_data.push({id: lineItemMeta[0].id}); // This works
         APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data.push({id: lineItemMeta[k].id}); // Doesn't work
         Logger.log(i+' '+j+' '+k); //prints out "0 0 0"
         Logger.log(APIPayloadObject.update[0].line_items[0].meta_data); // prints out "[]" so it looks like the meta_data array exist
      }
      }
   }
}
```

Do you have any idea why counter variables can't be used to push elements into the Object?

Comment: Does the value you are trying to push get to the if condition?

Comment: Depending on other code, the actual `condition`, etc, it may hurt that you did not explicitly declare the loop variables. Use `for(let i=`, `for(let j=`, `for(let k=`,... It is anyway bad practice to not do that, and can lead to unexpected behaviour if you use those variables elsewhere or recursively. BTW: "doesn't work" is not a good problem description. You should describe the behaviour precisely, and what you expected to happen instead. Did you debug and inspect those variables?

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that all entries `APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j]` actually exist for all the values of `i` and `j` you use? The code is not at all proving that... Can you provide code with which we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys, I shouldn't remove Object declaring lines. Maybe I don't build up the Object the proper way but that works. `.push()` only fail inside the if condition. Maybe that cause the problem, but still not clear to me why. The `.push()` command doesn't throw any error simly just don't push anything into the `meta_data` array.

Comment: This code runs in Google Apps script, `let` is not available. I added `for(var i=0;` for every loop without succes.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. The `APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data = [];` line should be inside the if condition, otherwise the content of  meta_data si always overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Counter variables are not working because you are not declaring the the properties properly.

```
APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data
```

Here you have to declare `update[i]`, `line_items` for each `update`, `meta_data` for each `line_items` .

Try the following code, it may resolve your issue:

```
var APIPayloadObject = {};
APIPayloadObject.update = [];

for(i=0; i < orders.length; i++){
   //Declaration part
   APIPayloadObject.update[i] = {};
   APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items = [];
   for(j=0; j < lineItems.length; j++){
   //Declaration part
   APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j] = {};
   APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data = [];
      for(k=0; k < lineItemMeta.length; k++){

      if(condition){
         APIPayloadObject.update[0].line_items[0].meta_data.push({id: lineItemMeta[0].id}); // This works
         APIPayloadObject.update[i].line_items[j].meta_data.push({id: lineItemMeta[k].id}); // Doesn't work
         console.log(i+' '+j+' '+k); //prints out "0 0 0"
      }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I think the source of the problem is not the declaration. I extended my code with declaration lines. Please see above.